# Spring JPA LAZY load OneToOne relation won't load

Tags: java, spring, jpa, one-to-one

i have a LAZY OneToOne relationship, 
and i want to load it per use (The same model have more OneToOne relations and i want to do less queries to the Database.)

Looking at the native db queries in the log file, i can see the when i am not trying to access to `user.city` the `SELECT FROM City...` statement is not printed.

but when accessing `user.city` i can see the SQL Statement running in the log, i am getting the class instance. but all filled inside the `City` entity are `null`, see below more info:

this code:

```
System.out.println(user.city);
System.out.println(user.city.location);
```

will print

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        city0_.id as id1_3_0_,
        city0_.accentName as accentNa2_3_0_,
        city0_.location as location3_3_0_,
        city0_.name as name4_3_0_,
        city0_.state_id as state_id5_3_0_ 
    from
        City city0_ 
    where
        city0_.id=?
com.dateup.models.City@1ed01095
null
```

Thous are my models :

```
@Entity
@Table(
    indexes={@Index(name = "name", columnList="name")}
)
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public State state;

    public String name;
    public String accentName;

    @Column(name = "location", columnDefinition = "POINT")
    public Point location;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name="User"
)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("'User'")
@JsonAutoDetect 
public abstract class BaseUser { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public City city;

    ...
}
```

---

Just to mention that when testing this with `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` all is working fine..

thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Are there missing setters or @Entity(access = AccessType.FIELD) a problem?

Comment: @maszter my fields are public, what to you mean 'r @Entity(access = AccessType.FIELD) a problem?'

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do one-to-one.

... in city class:

`@ManyToOne state;` (I usually do EAGER for one side, lazy for other; `(FetchType.EAGER, CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy='city')`)

... in state class:

`@OneToMany city;` (a state has many cities).

Are you sure you have an INSERT statement somewhere in your logs, which adds the correct city with the correct id ?

It's hard to know without seeing all the code.

Comment: here the city class have no relation back to the user. cause this city can be used by many users

Comment: Also I don't know why you have User as an abstract class? Is that right?

Comment: i used to have a inheritance before, so baseUser stayed for may be trying again latter... i have a User class that extend the BaseUser, do you think this can be related ?

Comment: No reason why "JPA" would need setters; ample ways of setting FIELDS

Comment: @NeilStockton correct, i forgot... ALSO Shay, check edited answer above. It's hard to tell what your issue is without seeing if you even added something into city table. EAGER loading for testing is also a good idea.

Comment: i know for sure this User have a City,  i forgot to mention before that @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) just for testing is working.
what should i do in my User class?, i tried @ManyToOne, but have the same results (sorry for the late response)